# How to suppress Joomla's JUser::_load:Unable to load user with id error message?

Tags: php, joomla, joomla1.6

I have a Joomla 1.6 installation that operates on two databases: joomla's database and domain-specific database, both on the same MySQL server. Some entities in the domain-specific database keeps their ownership links, i.e. stores user_id of Joomla user that created it. Some of the links are inconsistent and points to non-existent Joomla user, it is normal from domain model point of view. The problem is when I try to get user name it shows

```
JUser::_load:Unable to load user with id 1
```

Since it is OK to have such links, I need to suppress this messages. The exact code that retrieves user name is just the following:

```
$user_id = $ticket->getUserId();
$user =& JFactory::getUser($user_id);
```

Wrappig this code into `ob_start() ... ob_end_clean()` does not help.
Of course I could do it by hacking Joomla's internals, but is there any cleaner solution? I'm new to Joomla, so maybe there is some option in admin panel to suppress those messages?

**UPDATE:** Setting display_errors=>off, html_errors=>off, display_startup_errors=>off noes not help. Using PHP error suppression with @ as `$user =@ JFactory::getUser($user_id)` does not help too.

Comment: If it says "Unable to load user with id 1" are you sure such user exists?

Comment: I'm absolutely sure that this user not exist. But it is a valid data, so I need to suppress this message

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Why don't you simply do pre-check if the user exists and then run your code:

```
$table   = JUser::getTable();
$user_id = intval( $ticket->getUserId() );

if($table->load( $user_id ))
{
         $user =& JFactory::getUser($user_id);
         // now you are sure user exists
} else {
         // user doesn't exists
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can turn off the displaying of error message in the configuration:

- On Tab Server, set **Error Reporting** to none.
- (Maybe also:) On Tab System, set **Debug System** to No.

Comment: Debug system is set to No. I'll check error reporting later, but as I remember it is set to none too.

Comment: Error reporting was set to Maximum, but setting it to none does not help.